# Why is the geth ipc file not being created, even though it says "endpoint opened"?

Tags: go-ethereum, ipc, bug

I had some test code working fine over IPC using out-of-the-box geth. I tried to set up a test network and it broke the IPC client.

I want to run two processes -- a miner geth process, which stands in for the community at large, and an IPC server geth process, which stands in for what would be running on my own web server.

Here is the script which captures what I think I should be doing.

```
#!/bin/bash

E="/store/ethereum/"

H="/store/home/"

D="$H/.ethereum-test"

G="geth --networkid 1100 --maxpeers 5"

PORT="--port 33301"

RPC="--rpcport 33302"

WSRPC="--wsport 33303"

IPC="--ipcapi 'admin,eth,miner,db,net,web3,personal' --ipcpath \"$E/geth.ipc\""

MINE="--mine  --minerthreads 1 -rpccorsdomain \"*\""

KS="--keystore \"$E/keystore\""

if [[ "$1" == "setup" ]]
then
    # Start fresh
    rm -rf "$D-miner"
    rm -rf "$D-client"

    # Accept conditions and type exit.
    $G --genesis test-genesis.json -nodiscover -maxpeers 0 --datadir "$D-miner" console
elif [[ "$1" == "newacc" ]]
then
    # Enter passphrase and note address.
    # Last generated address:
    # bcd47eee60f5d8f73977785a55ab081bf8f37582
    # 5b3e83ff30e61287cf2d8eed5b8c1ead40d10432
    # a770c607f4bde0cdf1fa84e8721e9b53fce8a176
    # (older)
    $G $KS --datadir $D-miner account new
elif [[ "$1" == "mine" ]]
then
    # Mine
    $G $MINE $KS --datadir $D-miner $PORT
elif [[ "$1" == "ipc" ]]
then
    $G --datadir $D-client $IPC
else
    echo "Argument: setup newacc mine or ipc"
fi
```

I use it like this.

In terminal A:

```
./testnet setup
./testnet newacc
./testnet mine
```

Mining works fine.

In terminal B:

```
./testnet ipc
```

This one appears to work fine. It outputs that it created `$E/geth.ipc` as promised.

Then here is the NodeJS which worked fine before:

```
var web3_extended = require ('web3_extended');

var options =
{
        host:     './geth.ipc',
        ipc:      true,
        personal: true, 
        admin:    false,
        debug:    false
};

var web3 = web3_extended .create (options);
```

This yields

```
IPC Connection Error { [Error: connect ENOENT] code: 'ENOENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'connect' }
```

What's odd is that geth in terminal B outputs this line

```
I0427 12:53:00.381003 node/node.go:298] IPC endpoint opened: "/ethereum/geth.ipc"
```

But if I `ls /ethereum/geth.ipc`

No such file is created (as it was with vanilla geth). Yes, I have write permissions to this directory. The miner in terminal A creates its geth.ipc elsewhere.

What's gone wrong?

**EDIT**

Miner produces [this output](http://pastebin.com/2EFx0s97) when started with

```
geth --networkid 1100 --maxpeers 5 --mine --minerthreads 1 -rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir /ethereum/.ethereum-test-miner --port 33301
```

And IPC server produces [this output](http://pastebin.com/G8htc6TN) when started with

```
geth --networkid 1100 --maxpeers 5 --datadir /ethereum/.ethereum-test-client --ipcapi 'admin,eth,miner,db,net,web3,personal' --ipcpath "/ethereum/geth.ipc"
```

Comment: Could you please open a bug report on our issue tracker? https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues

Answer (score 3):

(This page will be reorganised when this problem is solved)

## EDIT 30/04/2016

@spraff, looking at your latest data:

> Miner produces [this output](http://pastebin.com/G8htc6TN) when started with
>
> ```
> geth --networkid 1100 --maxpeers 5 --mine --minerthreads 1 -rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir /ethereum/.ethereum-test-miner --port 33301
> ```
>
> And IPC server produces [this output](http://pastebin.com/G8htc6TN) when started with
>
> ```
> geth --networkid 1100 --maxpeers 5 --datadir /ethereum/.ethereum-test-client --ipcapi 'admin,eth,miner,db,net,web3,personal' --ipcpath "/ethereum/geth.ipc"
> ```

the IPC file paths look correct. It does however seems like you are trying to link your miner with your IPC client using the IPC protocol.

The IPC protocol is meant to link a node (mining or non-mining) to a client (e.g. console viewer like `geth attach ipc://path/geth.ipc`, Ethereum Wallet or web client).

What you probably want to do is to create a private Ethereum network with both your mining clients and non-mining clients connected to the same blockchain network. This is done using the same `--networkid` and `--genesis` flags, **AND** you then link all mining and non-mining clients using the `--bootnodes` parameter, or using either the `static-nodes.json` or `trusted-nodes.json` configuration file.

You can find the method to link the clients at [Peer discovery not working on private network](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2708/peer-discovery-not-working-on-private-network/2709#2709) . Some information is also available at [Connection between peers never happen on custom blockchain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2258/connection-between-peers-never-happen-on-custom-blockchain/3122#3122) .

## OLD STUFF BELOW

---

## Question For @spraff

1. What version `geth` are you running in your different terminals?

   You seem to be running the **develop** branch version of `geth` in the terminal where you are encountering the `--ipcpath` issue.

   You may want to try using the **master** branch version of `geth` where the `--ipcpath` seems to be working.

   You should still lodge a bug report as suggested by `@Péter Szilágyi` if the `--ipcpath` does not work with the **develop** branch version of `geth`.
2. Is there more than one version of `geth` installed on your computer (and in your different terminals) ? Check with the commands:

   ```
   find / -name 'geth'
   ls -al `which geth`
   ```

   Are you running the version of `geth` that you intend to run?

---

## Unrolling your commands

Your script file is a little bit complicated to read, so I've unrolled the commands.

### Terminal A

```
# ./testnet setup
rm -rf /store/home//.ethereum-test-miner
rm -rf /store/home//.ethereum-test-client
geth --networkid 1100 --maxpeers 5                    \
  --genesis test-genesis.json -nodiscover -maxpeers 0 \
  --datadir "/store/home//.ethereum-test-miner" console

# ./testnet newacc
geth --networkid 1100 --maxpeers 5      \
  --keystore "/store/ethereum//keystore" \
  --datadir /store/home//.ethereum-test-miner account new

# ./testnet mine
geth --networkid 1100 --maxpeers 5            \
  --mine  --minerthreads 1 -rpccorsdomain "*" \
  --keystore "/store/ethereum//keystore"      \
  --datadir /store/home//.ethereum-test-miner \
  --port 33301
```

### Terminal B

```
# ./testnet ipc
geth --networkid 1100 --maxpeers                  \
  --datadir /store/home//.ethereum-test-client    \
  --ipcapi 'admin,eth,miner,db,net,web3,personal' \
  --ipcpath "/store/ethereum//geth.ipc"
```

> This one appears to work fine. It outputs that it created $E/geth.ipc as promised.

So the IPC file `/store/ethereum/geth.ipc` is created as expected

> What's odd is that geth in terminal B outputs this line
>
> ```
> I0427 12:53:00.381003 node/node.go:298] IPC endpoint opened: "/ethereum/geth.ipc"
> ```
>
> But if I `ls /ethereum/geth.ipc`
>   No such file is created (as it was with vanilla geth). Yes, I have write permissions to this directory. The miner in terminal A creates its geth.ipc elsewhere.
>   What's gone wrong?

---

#### Issue 1 - What version of `geth` are you running, or intend to run?

I've found [node/node.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/develop/node/node.go#L297-L299) in the go-ethereum **develop** branch with the following code:

```
go func() {
    glog.V(logger.Info).Infof("IPC endpoint opened: %s", n.ipcEndpoint)
```

When I run `geth` on my computer, I get the following message:

```
I0428 00:42:38.207812   14842 ipc.go:112] IPC service started (/home/user/.ethereum/geth.ipc)
instance: Geth/v1.3.6/linux/go1.5.1
```

The `--ipcpath` command works correctly in my version of `geth`:

```
$ geth --ipcpath /tmp/geth.ipc console

I0428 01:24:01.896976   20433 ipc.go:112] IPC service started (/tmp/geth.ipc)
instance: Geth/v1.3.6/linux/go1.5.1
```

---

## Testing IPC

I've used your latest command to test out the IPC file path:

```
user@Kumquat:/tmp$ geth --networkid 1100 --maxpeers 5 \
  --datadir ./eth/.ethereum-test-client               \
  --ipcapi 'admin,eth,miner,db,net,web3,personal'     \
  --ipcpath "./eth/geth.ipc"

...

I0428 09:14:09.309467   22639 cmd.go:115] Starting Geth/v1.3.6/linux/go1.5.1
I0428 09:14:10.789959   22639 ipc.go:112] IPC service started (eth/geth.ipc)
```

So it seems to be working for my `geth` version on Linux.

Here is your `geth` command with the output you provided in your link:

```
geth --networkid 1100 --maxpeers 5                \
  --datadir /eth/.ethereum-test-client            \
  --ipcapi 'admin,eth,miner,db,net,web3,personal' \
  --ipcpath "/eth/geth.ipc"
...
I0427 22:24:27.875773   30370 cmd.go:115] Starting Geth/v1.3.6/linux/go1.5.1
I0427 22:24:30.222976   30370 ipc.go:112] IPC service started ("/ethereum/geth.ipc")
```

But it is not working for your `geth` version on Linux as well.

**Note**: `/ethereum` is on your root directory. Normally processes cannot create files on the root directory without superuser permission. Perhaps this is the reason.

I've just re-tested using the command:

```
geth --networkid 1100 --maxpeers 5                \
  --datadir ./eth/.ethereum-test-client           \
  --ipcapi 'admin,eth,miner,db,net,web3,personal' \
  --ipcpath "/ethereum/geth.ipc"
```

And this is the error message I get:

```
Fatal: Error string IPC: mkdir /ethereum: permission denied
```

I created the subdirectory `/ethereum` without changing the permissions:

```
sudo mkdir /ethereum
```

And running the last `geth` command again, get a different error message:

```
Fatal: Error string IPC: listen unix /ethereum/geth.ipc: bind: permission denied
```

I'm now changing the ownership of the directory:

```
sudo chown user:user /ethereum
```

And it works:

```
I0428 09:29:10.777981   22740 ipc.go:112] IPC service started (/ethereum/geth.ipc)
```

Hmmm. I'll think about it a bit more.

Comment: Thanks this looks very helpful! I was running `Version: 1.5.0-unstable` from Ubuntu ethereum-dev PPA, purged it and reinstalled `Version: 1.3.6` -- this could quite possibly be it although this version doesn't have the `--keystore` flag. Can you please comment on this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you need to set the keystore directory to anything other than under the --datadir sub directory, just use soft links as demonstrated in http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3402/move-ethash-directory-out-of-home .

Comment: No, this isn't it. I dropped the keystore flags but the issue persists when I'm running 1.3.6 HOWEVER the command `geth --ipcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal" --ipcpath "$P/geth.ipc"` works as normal (for the same binary) it's just that now I'm not on the testnet.

Comment: Can you provide the full details of the 1.3.6 command that does not work, with the options all expanded?

Comment: Miner: `geth --networkid 1100 --maxpeers 5 --mine --minerthreads 1 -rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir /eth/.ethereum-test-miner --port 33301` IPC server: `geth --networkid 1100 --maxpeers 5 --datadir /eth/.ethereum-test-client --ipcapi 'admin,eth,miner,db,net,web3,personal' --ipcpath "/eth/geth.ipc"`

Comment: Is it only the IPC Server version that is not working? What happens when you add a "console" at the end of this command? Can you add the initial start up messages to the end of your original question?

Comment: No worries. Ethereum.SE is part of my research into Ethereum. I found my first use case using smart contracts for a client yesterday, so I'm satisfied.  I'll test your command line options against your output in a few hours.

Comment: I've tested using your command and got different results from you. I'll have to think about it a bit more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39020/discussion-between-spraff-and-bokkypoobah).